# GWT celltable: columns unreachable by keyboard navigation

Tags: gwt, celltable, gwt-celltable

In the showcase example of CellTable:
http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable

It is possible to click in the (right-most) address column, the row becomes yellow and the cell is framed in gray. By hitting the UP and DOWN keys, I can choose a different row, and the address is framed. By hitting the LEFT and RIGHT keys, it is possible to frame in gray cells of different columns.

BUT… After leaving the address column using the LEFT or RIGHT keys, it is not possible to go back. The address column is skipped, maybe because it is not editable or something.

Is there a way to have an non-editable column accessible by keyboard? I know it may serve no purpose, but I have a similar table, and I find this behavior annoying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the code for [`AbstractCellTable`](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/AbstractCellTable.java), it only moves focus to a column when processing left/right keys if the column is "interactive", i.e. if the `Cell` for the column *consumes* some events. In the showcase, the address column uses a `TextCell` which doesn't process any event, so it's not possible to move the focus to that column using the keyboard.

Comment: As I feared. Maybe I can add a bogus event to these cells just so they are not skipped…

Comment: You could have `getConsumedEvents` return `click` but not do anything with it (in `onBrowserEvent`)